# PHP socket connections: read and send data in loop

Tags: php, sockets, loops

I have to make a function, in which I send a packet to server and then read data. After a while I sometimes require to send a data to server again using the same socket (it's required that I use the same one).

For some reason second send, which is after read doesn't send data (it returns correct number (not false), but server doesn't receive packet). If I create new socket and send data - it works.

Here is an example:

```
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
socket_connect($socket, '192.168.1.179', 1455);
socket_set_option($socket,SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, array("sec"=>5, "usec"=>0));

$this->socket_functions->send_message($socket,$sendMsg,$funcName);
$tmp = trim($this->socket_functions->read_packet($socket));

for($i =0; $i<10; $i++)
{
    $tmp = trim($this->socket_functions->read_packet($socket));

    $this->socket_functions->send_message($socket, 'AAAA', $funcName);      //doesn't work
    /*
    ///works
    $socket2 = $this->socket_functions->create_socket();
    $this->socket_functions->send_message($socket2, 'AAAA', $funcName);
    $this->socket_functions->disconnect($socket2);
    */
}
```

Function create_socket does the same as first 3 lines so the connection data is the same. I just brought it out so you are able to see my configuration.

For read and write I use functions socket_send() and socket_write().

Read packet function:

```
    $resultMsg = "";
    while(strlen($currentData = socket_read($socket,256))==256) 
    {
        $resultMsg .=$currentData;
    }
    $resultMsg.=$currentData;

    if(strlen($resultMsg)>1 && strpos($resultMsg,'<')>0)
    {
        $resultMsg = substr($resultMsg,strpos($resultMsg,'<'));
    }
    return $resultMsg;
```

Sending packet:

```
function create_packet($msg, $type)     
{
    $msg = $type.$this->convert_data->IntToAsciiChars(strlen($msg)).$msg;
    $msg = chr(0).$this->convert_data->IntToAsciiChars(strlen($msg)).$msg;
    return $msg;
}

function send_message($socket,$msg,$type)
{
    $packet = $this->create_packet($msg,$type);
    $res = socket_send($socket,$packet,strlen($packet),0);
    if($res === false) return false;
    return true;
}
```

**EDIT**

I did more testing and found out, that this only occurs, if the server, to which I'm connected keeps sending data. As in - the server sends multiple packets in row. If I try to send packet before the server has sent all of them, the packet isn't received. Does anyone knows why is this happening? I have desktop application, which does the same thing (sends data using the same socket while server is sending data), but it works there. Is there something specific?

Comment: Have you tried using tcpdump to see if the data is being sent?

Comment: What does `$this` refer to? Should that be `$socket`?

Comment: You're talking about packets but TCP works based on streams. My bet is that you've done something wrong. Unless you explicitly split it up into packets, there is no guarantee that your first read call won't read more than one "packet". How about if you show the code for `read_packet` (and maybe `send_message`)?

Comment: I added read_packet function.

Answer (score 1):

I finally managed to fix this. After testing I found out, if I *used send **n+1** times to send the message, where **n** is amount of times read was called* , I was able to send a message then.

I really don't know why this worked - maybe someone here knows?

Comment: It may be a bug in the server, or the server takes first **n** messages as a kind of acknowledge of his messages.